# JavaFX - Button to minimize the stage

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have an undecorated stage in a JavaFX Application. In order to minimize it I need a minimize button. I created my layout in an `fxml document` which has a `minimize button`, but when I try to minimize using the `action listener` for this button located inside the controller using `stage.setIconified(true)`, it cannot find stage.

How can I find a reference to the stage in the controller class?

Comment: What does "cannot find the stage" mean ? Do you have an error message ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try :

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    ((Stage)((Button)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow()).setIconified(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution number 1 is what ItachiUchiha posted.

Solution number 2 is just creating a setter-method in the controller and give the controller the stage itself.

Comment: I'm curious; what's the benefit of this over ItachiUchiha's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this
`Stage stage = (Stage) minimize.getScene().getWindow(); stage.setIconified(true); // minimize can be any element in that scene`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this will work and why please :)

Comment: and stick to java naming conventions, please